# Can unity places be written in C++?

Tags: unity, c++

Is C++ a supported language for writing unity places?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There exists a library called libunity which is a native wrapper over unity dbus api. Since c++ can link to native libraries, so you can write your apps in C++.

Also check kamstrup's ubuntu develop week session on libunity. I can't search for it since I am on phone with pretty slow network speed.

**UPDATE**: Here is the link. Thanks to [`ris`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30096/can-unity-places-be-written-in-c/30125#30125) 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/devweek1103/RockingOutwithlibunity

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/devweek1103/RockingOutwithlibunity

Comment: Indeed Manish is correct. In fact, the Applications place in Unity is written in mixed C++ and Vala.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, there is this post (link below), but it says Python:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/making-your-own-unity-place/